# How to insert AM and PM in Mysql Database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is my value, I am going to insert in my DB

```
[phoneinterview] => 2018-05-16 10:28 PM
```

In My databse I have field like this

```
phoneinterview  timestamp
```

But Its Inserting Like this:

```
2018-05-16 10:28:00
```

Actually I want to insert like this:

```
2018-05-16 10:28 PM
```

Comment: what datatype you have used for storing date ? is it the datetime ?

Comment: In My DB I used timestamp to store the data

Comment: You can use `varchar` datatype, but it's not good for it. You can use `->format()` as you want to display it! Like: `->format('g:i A');`

Comment: Thank you all now its working properly, while inserting in Database I change h:i:s to H:i:s, While retrieving these value i used g:i A

Comment: The general lesson to take away from this is that you should always store data in a computer-readable format, and only convert it to human-readable form when you want to display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `datetime` field in your database you can't, but if you change the field to a `varchar` then you are able to save it the way you like it. I would recommend against it. Why would you want to save a formatted time? It is best practice to save the date in a `datetime` field, and then when you want to show it format the way you want to. In Laravel you can do this using a mutator like this:

```
public function getPhoneinterviewAttribute() {
    return \Carbon\Carbon::now(
        $this->attributes['phoneinterview']
    )->format('g:i A');
}
```

Plus side: When you are expanding to areas where people don't use AM/PM then you can easily format it to their locale.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. When you are selecting timestamp or datetime datatypes for storing date, it does not store the AM and PM values in the database table fields. The best solution for this is you retrieve the date and convert that into date and time along with AM/PM manually.

One alternate solution is using the datatype of varchar instead of timestamp but that is not recommendable.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses the format `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` to store dates, so if you're using anything other than that, you need to convert it to this format first. This can be done with [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d g:i a', '2018-05-16 10:28 PM');
```

This will create a DateTime object that you can easily format for MySQL:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `datetime` datatype it's storing `2018-05-16 10:28:00`. But if you want to store `AM/PM` you need to use `varchar` datatype.

I suggest you to use `->format();` while you get the timestamp data. This will convert the date time format as your wish.

For now, as you want to display `AM/PM` after time, use it like: `->format('g:i A');` This will show time like `10:28 PM`.

Hope this helps you!!